# how to type define a zip function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I want to create a `zip` function:

```js
function zip(arrays){
    // assume more than 1 array is given and all arrays 
    // share the same length
    const len = arrays[0].length;
    const toReturn = new Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        toReturn[i] = arrays.map(array=>array[i]);
    }
    return toReturn;
}

console.log(zip([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12],
]));
/*
Output:
(3) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) [1, 4, 7, 10]
1: (4) [2, 5, 8, 11]
2: (4) [3, 6, 9, 12]
*/
```

In order to type define this function when all arrays hold the same type of elements:

```js
    function zip<T>(arrays: T[][]): T[][]{/* codes omited here */}
```

However, when arrays are of different types of elements, I get confused about how to use generic type to finish the type definition.

```js
    const zipedResult = zip([[1,2,3],[true,false,true],['a','b','c']]);
    // error raises: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

what I want is

```js
    [[1,2,3],[true,false,true],['a','b','c']]
```

could be automatically infered as `(number|boolean|string)[][]` without writing `as (number|boolean|string)[][]`
or EVEN
infered as `[number[],boolean[],string[]]` and result of `zip` infered as `[number, boolean, string][]`

How should I correctly type define `zip` to fullfill such features?

Comment: [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) has [zip](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/index.html#zip) operator, which works well, both synchronously and asynchronously. And, you can check for its TypeScript declarations [in the source](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/blob/main/src/ops/zip.ts) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that works for me:

```js
export function zip<T extends unknown[][]>(
  ...args: T
): { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (infer V)[] ? V : never }[] {
  const minLength = Math.min(...args.map((arr) => arr.length));
  // @ts-expect-error This is too much for ts
  return range(minLength).map((i) => args.map((arr) => arr[i]));
}
```

for example `zip(["x", "y", "z"], [true, false, true])` has inferred type `[string, boolean][]`

Comment: also big plus for using @ts-expect-error as a bail-out for when types become far too complex to be useful

Answer (score 2):

The solutions above are all valid and should work for normal use cases. We normally don't really know what elements are inside the array we would pass into the `zip` function. So the return type of

```
zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])
```

being

```
[number, string][]
```

is fine for most cases where arbitrary arrays are passed into the function.

But **if the elements are known at compile time**, TypeScript allows us to have more accurate return types. We can change the defintion of `zip`, so that the return type of `zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])` is

```
[[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

Here is a solution that accomplishes this:

```
type ValidContent =
  | null
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | Array<JSON>
  | Date
  | undefined
  | {
    [prop: string]: ValidContent
  }

type ZipReturn<T extends any[][]> = T[0] extends infer A 
  ? { 
      [K in keyof A]: [...{ 
        [K2 in keyof T]: K extends keyof T[K2] ? T[K2][K] : undefined 
      }] 
    }
  : never

function zip<
  T extends [...{[K in keyof S]: S[K]}][], S extends (ValidContent)[]
>(...arrays: [...T]): ZipReturn<T> {
  const maxLength = Math.max(...arrays.map((x) => x.length));

  return range(maxLength).map((_, i) => {
    return range(arrays.length).map((_, k) => arrays[k][i]);
  }) as unknown as ZipReturn<T>;
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
const a = zip([1, 2, 3])
//   ^? [[1], [2], [3]]

const b = zip([1, 2, undefined], ["a", "b", "c"])
//   ^? [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [undefined, "c"]]

const c = zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"], [new Date(), new Date(), new Date()])
//   ^? [[1, "a", Date], [2, "b", Date], [3, "c", Date]]

const d = zip([1, 2, 3] as number[], ["a", "b", "c"] as string[])
//   ^? [number, string][]
```

As you can see in the last example, the function still works fine for arbitrary array types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwIZgOYFMAUBnGALywC5EwQBbAIy2QBpE8pVkoBBKMimuxAXkQAGAJRkASllQATBABsAnu2RoFAHh61kAPkQBvAFCIUWKCGRIA2gDpby1fiJYR1gNZYFeHCIC61yqgADjg4MCICujCIANRMLGycIgDcBgC%20BgZQCoFYiABqqHIw0gDCCFBYYFACRogAPuQgcnK1DczIMJitjbzI3dRwcHJSYN32qOoAUgDKAPIActrdACKoFd3g0ljAnVjS3YbGxpaByHCBZO2dGD5kBUWl5ZVQtemZ2bkAWjCBkmYWagAKogsAAPCpgaR4RDoBSWHzw3SCQGWIQ%20EHgypQxCdYB8diIWoAfn0iEsAGkcUh3Ao4MBEOxbmTbNY9GTyQAmKmIGl0xCApmUsEQ7G8%20koznokkSjkI8nosibba7aSIVLo9LGbhYABudAyoEgsAQiEIPzUtWBwqx0Jstj0FO5YsQ0yZ0wpPnV8MY0wxIuhOHuxTKVWeInhBm0OBZrFUeDIdusArEiG%20v1M5jAQN0h0QEAQzEQAVBABlKhgoAALASIACya0r-lQoOjtljEzwTeCOFB4X4ulB1mGmCrImSGWMyAzFhQ6GwOGLZZHlZcAW7AH1GGEIvpapPp0g0JhcO3PEPy6OuyFNzy%207pT3hLK4ETAfOPjKlwqhoeBXGA4AA7kg36pj8fyZtmKRvPmYCFqgNZmsElgAIyMByjAAMxvgYAD0OFHAAeiSlgoT4jCWLK5FYT4GQwYW1AIT8OAoWhjBKjsYB7GRZIAESoDxjA8dQAmIDxEA8dheGEcRLGifx3EUYJwkKexKqCeJPg0QYdHVBAjFIahiDoYgWHkXxIlCRZGnkZxAGIKsFTeIwtn2WsuAiM5WB2Q57mSfhxhEWSsnmYwPkKcZlmhW5CkYepIlhVpOmIKqgiIcxhnGVhMLQpodDerx-FKVZEnZXEHSYPCIi4f5iCBZYuUMGV1wIj4QA)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this is to define a different `zip` function for each size of array you'd like to handle (as we need to be able to say exactly *what* is in each part of the zip result):

```js
const zip3 = <T, U, V>(arrays: [T[], U[], V[]]): [T, U, V][] => {
    const len = arrays[0].length;
    const toReturn: [T, U, V][] = new Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        toReturn[i] = [arrays[0][i], arrays[1][i], arrays[2][i]];
    }
    return toReturn;
};

const result = zip3([
    [1,2,3],
    [true, false, true],
    [7,8,9],
]);

console.log(result);
```

Hopefully someone can come in and show a better way to do this, without having to redefine the function dependent on how many arrays you'd like to zip;

Comment: I've read lib.es2015.promise.d.ts where `Promise.all` is defined in a similar tricky way. However I  still don't think it a good idea to define zip<T1> to zip<T1,...,T10>. Is there any other way to handle non-fixed length and no-fixed element types at the same time?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts

Comment: @TTY112358 I think that, yes, there probably is; I'm taking another look at this to try and figure out whether it's possible

Comment: @TTY112358 I think the difficult thing about this is that we're not trying to return any `T[]`, but rather some tuple, of unknown size, with any number of different types

Comment: what about we define `zip` in this way: `zip<T extends any[]>(arrays: HigherOrderArrayOf<T>):T[]`. So now the problem is how to write `HigherOrderArrayOf`

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEglgcwBYQE4HlUBM0EFWoCGI6AZgDwAqAfFALxQDeA2gNJRwB2UA1hCAHtSUSgF0AXCLajmogL4BuAFBLSAV04BjYHAHcAXnDBUoEAB7AInLAGcohTiFnUAFIQLEbk+MjSYcqPhEJBQ0AJSSlLKMSlBxUJp6NsBQADZW9PYeIDbMAAyiAHTpnAjASMrxCUkpwAIAShDAaqjcDJwQAO5QQcQuJWGV8aQCqFD9TRyZeQpT5GlWs3AA1MthMVVVdY3NrcxwopnuwTaFALaEYG7ZdNTHxPuig7Hxci9xqE0t3NtfrcpvJSJTjJKCfGxqVIpBiGYzMThqM4AIzQABooMlUFwEKJXMxmABGVEAJlRAGZRKjmAByQjU9HUpH0qDUzTU0RPBRAA) Does this suggest that typescript always requires caller to decide the length of a tuple instead of inferring its length?

Comment: [a better example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kqwjb5) use this link instead

Comment: I think that yes, you'd need to specify the types, but also it seems like a union type is the best you'll get, ie: `(string | number)[]` instead of `[string, number]`

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution would be:

```
declare type UnionTypes = number[] | string[] | boolean[];
function zip(arrays: UnionTypes[]): UnionTypes[]
```

Comment: I'm afraid the returned type should be (number | string | boolean)[][] with `const zipedResult = zip([[1,2,3],[true,false,true],['a','b','c']]);
console.log(zipedResult); // [[1, true, "a"], [2, false, "b"], [3, true, "c" ]]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one of the few times when you see the complications of TS not being useful. I can only think of relaxing the type to just `any` and do manual type checking when necessary.

```
function zip(arrays: any[][]): any[][]{
    // assume more than 1 array is given and all arrays 
    // share the same length
    const len = arrays[0].length;
    const toReturn = new Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        toReturn[i] = arrays.map(array => array[i]);
    }
    return toReturn;
}

const zipedResult = zip([[1,2,3],[true,false,true],['a','b','c']]);
console.log(zipedResult); // [[1, true, "a"], [2, false, "b"], [3, true, "c" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

- fully typed
- accepts arrays of different types
- if the arrays do not have the same length, the result will have the length of the shorter array (which AFAIK is the most common implementation of `zip`)

```
function zip<A, B>(as: A[], bs: B[]): [A, B][]
{
    return as.length <= bs.length
         ? as.map((a, i) => [a, bs[i]])
         : bs.map((b, i) => [as[i], b])
}
```