# Type of zip and unzip array functions?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

I have zip and unzip functions like this:

```ts
function range(size: number, startAt: number = 0): ReadonlyArray<number> {
  return [...Array(size).keys()].map((i) => i + startAt);
}

function unzip<T extends unknown[]>(array: T[]) /* ??? */ {
  const maxLength = Math.max(...array.map((x) => x.length));

  return array.reduce(
    (acc, val) => {
      val.forEach((v, i) => acc[i].push(v));

      return acc;
    },
    range(maxLength).map(() => [])
  );
}

function zip<T extends unknown[]>(...arrays: T[]) /* ??? */ {
  const maxLength = Math.max(...arrays.map((x) => x.length));

  return range(maxLength).map((i) =>
    range(arrays.length).map((_, k) => arrays[k][i])
  );
}
```

I have no idea how to type the return types though. Is it even possible?

I think it would be nice if `zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"])` returned with a type of `[number | undefined, string | undefined][]`. It seems that there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70192772/8613630) as someone in the comments pointed out that does precisely this. Likewise, it would be nice if `unzip([1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, undefined])` returned a type of `[number[], string[]]` or maybe `[number[], (string | undefined)[]]` depending on whichever is easiest.

I am a typescript noob, so naturally I tried to find some types on the internet, but they all seem to go the "lazy" route and type returns as `any`.

If this is even possible, how would I type the return types of these two functions (as well as similar functions where you "invert" the type of an array)?

Comment: How strongly typed do you need the output to be?  Please give examples of inputs and the desired types of the outputs.  Depending how crazy you get, `zip([1,2,3],["a", "b"])` could produce a value of type anywhere from the loose `(number | string)[][]` to the more reasonable `[number | undefined, string | undefined][]` to the incredibly specific `[[1, "a"],[2, "b"],[3, undefined]]`.  Without more clarity in the question, this could have many possible  answers.

Comment: Here would be a solution for a `zip` function return type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70192772/8613630

Comment: Are you looking for smth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021405/ts-types-convert-arrays-of-keys-and-array-of-values-to-object#answer-67022175) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for `unzip` that does what you want.

```
function unzip<
  T extends [...{ [K in keyof S]: S[K] }][], S extends any[]
>(arr: [...T]): T[0] extends infer A 
  ? { [K in keyof A]: T[number][K & keyof T[number]][] } 
  : never 
{
  const maxLength = Math.max(...arr.map((x) => x.length));

  return arr.reduce(
    (acc: any, val) => {
      val.forEach((v, i) => acc[i].push(v));

      return acc;
    },
    range(maxLength).map(() => [])
  );
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
const a = unzip([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]])
//   ^? [number[], string[]]

const b = unzip([[1, "a", new Date()], [2, "b", new Date()], [3, "c", new Date()]] )
//   ^? [number[], string[], Date[]]

const c = unzip([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, undefined]])
//   ^? [number[], (string | undefined)[]]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220616#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwIZgOYFMAUBnGALywC5EwQBbAIy2QBpE8pVkoBBKMimuxAXkQAGAJRkASllQATBABsAnu2RoFAHh61kAPkQBvAFCIUWKCGRIA2gDpby1fiJYR1gNZYFeHCIC61yqgADjg4MCICujCIANRMLGycIgDcBgC+BgagkLAIiOCEMIFqRogAKohYAB5QWGDSeIg2tnqWANKIMEjuCnDAiADKPmT9bT6pPpY+jP0V1bX1iOgKkwbaOKzIZE3WpT5iZZZCPrM1dQ2dwHzsiAD8+o3tnYjdvYjsQweadBPtAGTPHlepUsX2QPgmx1SiG4WAAbnxDMYIAhmIgApUADK1DBQAAWAkQAFlUHj-KhKjhbNYNmTgjhKuF+LpKtY5Ni8SJkhljMhTOYkDTedIQBBcCVjOsIBAyEtGLDUHJGbpEcZVfK5NZgHBkABRVAQXEhWGMMIRRZSywwPyBEB4Q2wzkpcWq3lmCzmiApVWIVL0Z1oTC4dFYzAc2khJWNPYlLnpAzIsCo1AE-KFHCWSwARkYACJUDmpo0AEy56gFxiWADMuYgBejAHp66qAHp3eMoqCIagpsAFYIZ7OIPM5xhgLAAd0QABESbhfBWS0Oy6OJ9PZ95C1WayPyKuZzUN8cRAZGy2bu3E52ID2++ms7n85vFzmy5vq3k6lhgJ0sNJwcfT2MVsgA)

---

Here is an alternative solution that is fully compatible with the solution above. But for array literals, this will produce more accurate return types.

```
type ValidContent =
  | null
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | Array<JSON>
  | Date
  | undefined
  | {
    [prop: string]: ValidContent
  }

type UnzipReturn<T extends any[]> = T[0] extends infer A 
  ? { 
      [K in keyof A]: [...{
        [K2 in keyof T]: T[K2][K & keyof T[K2]]
      }] 
    } 
  : never

function unzip<
  T extends [...{[K in keyof S]: S[K]}][], S extends ValidContent[]
>(arr: [...T]): UnzipReturn<T> {
  const maxLength = Math.max(...arr.map((x) => x.length));

  return arr.reduce(
    (acc: any, val) => {
      val.forEach((v, i) => acc[i].push(v));

      return acc;
    },
    range(maxLength).map(() => [])
  );
}
```

```
const a = unzip([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]])
//   ^? [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]

const b = unzip([[1, "a", new Date()], [2, "b", new Date()], [3, "c", new Date()]] )
//   ^? [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"], [Date, Date, Date]]

const c = unzip([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, undefined]])
//   ^? [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", undefined]]

const d = unzip([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]] as [number, string][])
//   ^? [number[], string[]]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220616#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwIZgOYFMAUBnGALywC5EwQBbAIy2QBpE8pVkoBBKMimuxAXkQAGAJRkASllQATBABsAnu2RoFAHh61kAPkQBvAFCIUWKCGRIA2gDpby1fiJYR1gNZYFeHCIC61yqgADjg4MCICujCIANRMLGycIgDcBgC%20BgZQCoFYiABqqHIw0gDCCFBYYFACRogAPuQgcnK1DczIMJitjbzI3dRwcHJSYN32qOoAUgDKAPIActrdACKoFd3g0ljAnVjS3YbGxpaByHCBZO2dGD5kBUWl5ZVQtemZ2bkAqmCEMIGSZgsagAKogsAAPCpgaR4RDoBSWHy6QTAyxCHxgyGVGGITrAPjsRC1AD8%20iJRyOlgA0rikO4FHBgIh2LdEDZbIcKZSqQAmWmIemMxDA1mo3k%20amIABkAo8QrFPJ8PlqFNSGJViFS5MQ3CwADc6BlQJBYAhEOBfoE1LVQRCoTj2dY9JLOrKGUzpqzptSfGrEYxppj7bD7sUylVnoiDNocKxkGRHSKxIhvpaAeYwCDdJyIAhmIgAuCADKVDBQAAWAkQAFk1uX-KhwThbNY4w3gjhweF%20LpwdZhpgKyJkhljMhTBm4SprOPpCAILgNbGIBAyPDGHrCt3sxrjJu5NZgHBkABRVAQcshPWMMIROErywwPyBEB4S964cpXcmQFIc8QFJVXoDU0EwXBCxLQdyxcAIO23NkfBEWoRzeXMwHzVAqwtP4cEsSwAEZGAAIlQIifEYSweWI6gyIogBmYiIDIxCDAAelYo4AD1iQyND82oLCfhwvDCMQEiiMYMAsAAd0QVYKm8ci2SosSaMkmS5LWXBfHoxiJPIDT5O0pVECQ9iuJ4gw%20OqCBBMtXCCOI0ilMo6jaLZBjzWhbZdmkJUzI44xuN4vNqmkOzhMcsTnIolSiJolzPKIpiTNQWFLE0OhGCuTAJRY8yguJIA)

Comment: Wow, what a wonderfully detailed answer. Looks like I have some homework to do, figuring out how all of these types work! Thank you.